# @Input() not working

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am trying to change child component property from parent component using @Input() but it's not working. I got that working using shared service but I did understand what am I doing wrong and why it's not working using @Input()

I have created 2 buttons in child component whose text comes from @Input() data object from parent component. When I *double click* table row in which two buttons are there, buttons become disabled using shared service using @Input() isDisabled property. When I click *get* button in parent component data changes and changes get reflected. But when I try to enable buttons using isDisabled = false from parent component, changes are not getting reflected.

Here is link to codepen example : [angular 4 codepen example](https://codepen.io/ajinkya_b/project/editor/ZGgGNm)

**Child component**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { DataService } from './data.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'tr[app-myComp]',
    template: `
                    <td><button [disabled]="isDisabled">{{data.prop1}}</button></td>    
                    <td><button [disabled]="isDisabled">{{data.prop2}}</button></td>    
                `
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  subscription: Subscription;

  @Input()
  isDisabled: boolean;

  @Input()
  data: {prop1: number, prop2: number};

    constructor(public service: DataService) {
this.subscription = service.disabled$.subscribe(
            () => {
                    this.isDisabled = true;
            }
        );
    }

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

**Parent Component**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';

import { MyComponent } from './myComponent'
import { DataService } from './data.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-body',
  template: `<table>
                <tr class="">
                  <td>buttons</td>
                </tr>
                <tr app-myComp [isDisabled]="isDisabled" [data]="data" [isDisabled]="isDisabled" (dblclick)="makeDisabled()"></tr>
             </table>

<button (click)="getNewData()">Get</button>
            `,
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

  constructor(
    public service: DataService
  ){}

  isDisabled: boolean = false;
  data: {prop1: number, prop2: number} = {prop1: 13, prop2: 16};

  makeDisabled(): void {
    this.service.makeDisabled()
  }

  getNewData(): void {
    //service call
    this.data = {prop1: 45, prop2: 56};
    this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled;
    this.isDisabled = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: you should decide if you're going to use the service or the input to set that property. There is no reason to use both.

Comment: `makeDisabled()` should actually set `this.isDisabled=true`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @bryan60 thanks. I guess we can not use both service and Input() at the same time. if I remove subscription then Input works fine !

Comment: You are correct. One way input binding breaks if you try to change it outside of the binding. You also could've made it a 2 way bind and this would have worked, but there is no good argument for why you would want to set this both via service and via input.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you're subscribing to `disabled$` but in the subscription you're setting `this.isDisabled` to false instead of the value from the subscription. Try changing it to this:

```js
constructor(public service: DataService) {
  this.subscription = service.disabled$.subscribe(
    (isDisabled: boolean) => {
      this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
    }
  );
}
```